# Remove Fragments from Backstack using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am sure there are many questions similar to this problem. However, I could not find a solution to the problem I am in. The problem is that popBackStack funtion removes the fragment from backstack. However, it crashes when another new navigation happens. Let me give an example, I have three fragments, FragmentFirst, FragmentSecond, and FragmentThird. One navigation graph,

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_a"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.SecondFragment"
        android:label="SecondFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_secondFragment_to_thirdFragment"
            app:destination="@id/thirdFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.ThirdFragment"
        android:label="ThirdFragment" >
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

FirstFragment,

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
}
```

SecondFragment,

```
button2.setOnClickListener {
    view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment_to_thirdFragment)
}
```

ThirdFragment,

```
button3.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.firstFragment, true)
}
```

Now, I can navigate from First to Second, Second to Third, and Third to First. But When I press the button in First again, it crashes and the message is

```
id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment cannot be found from the current destination NavGraph
```

If I create an action in the graph like,

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
    android:name="com.example.myapplication.ThirdFragment"
    android:label="ThirdFragment" >
    <action
        app:popUpTo="@id/firstFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"
        android:id="@+id/action_thirdFragment_to_firstFragment"
        app:destination="@id/firstFragment" />
</fragment>
```

And in Fragment third,

```
button3.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_thirdFragment_to_firstFragment)
}
```

In this case, it works perfectly. However, I want to use popBackStack due to the constraints of the app I am working in.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you have deleted your first fragment and then you want to navigate to the first fragment how could this be done?!

Comment: @AfshinSamiei where did I delete my first Fragment? I just added the action to the third fragment to show where it is working. But I want to do the same thing without declaring that action in third fragment.

Comment: `popBackStack(R.id.firstFragment, true)` pops everything up to and inclusive to the first fragment. You've popped every fragment off the back stack. Seems like you want to use `false`, not `true` if you just want to return to the first fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake you are awesome. Yes, the value will be false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`popBackStack(R.id.firstFragment, true)` pops everything up to and inclusive to the first fragment. You've popped every fragment off the back stack. Seems like you want to use `false`, not `true` if you just want to return to the first fragment.